# Find coordinates x distance along linestring

Tags: r, r-sf

I would like to extract the coordinates of a point at a known distance along the linestring, starting from one end of the linestring.

For example:

```
library(sf)

path <- st_as_sfc('LINESTRING(10 20, 11 21, 12 21, 13 22)')
start_point <- st_as_sfc('POINT(10 20)')
nodes <- st_as_sfc('MULTIPOINT(10 20, 11 21, 12 21, 13 22)')

plot(st_geometry(path))
plot(st_geometry(nodes), add = T, pch = 16, col = 'grey')
plot(st_geometry(start_point), add = T, pch = 16, col = 'red')
```

[image: Example of line with starting point]

In the example code/image we have a linestring (nodes in grey) and the starting point (in this example the linestring starting coordinates) in red.

Example of desired output:

```
distance_line <- st_as_sfc('LINESTRING(10 20, 11 21, 11.5 21)')
point_wanted <- st_as_sfc('POINT(11.5 21)')  

plot(st_geometry(distance_line), col = 'green', lwd = 4, add = T)
plot(st_geometry(point_wanted), add = T, pch = 16, col = 'blue')
```

[image: The desired output]

Ultimately, I'm wanting to extract the coordinates (e.g. using `st_coordinates`) of the point at distance X along the linestring from the starting point. This feels like a common enough desire, so apologies if I have missed an obvious solution.

The only method I can see is to sample, using `sf::st_line_sample`, at a high resolution and extract the nearest value. This seems inefficient as I have many thousand linestrings with each only needing one distance coordinates. Ideally, the proposed method would be sf compatible.

**Updated with more realistic data**

```
path <- st_as_sf(data.frame(X = c(444618, 444640, 444661), Y = c(216561, 216556, 216550), L1 = 1), coords = c('X', 'Y'), crs = 27700) %>% 
      group_by(L1) %>%
      summarise(do_union = F) %>% 
      st_cast('LINESTRING')

nodes <- st_as_sf(data.frame(X = c(444618, 444640, 444661), Y = c(216561, 216556, 216550), L1 = 1), coords = c('X', 'Y'), crs = 27700)
```

Testing method proposed by @agila:

```
    st_distance(nodes)[1,]
    Units: [m]
    [1]  0.00000 22.56103 44.38468

Testing with point 2 and 3.
pt1 <- path %>% st_startpoint()

desired_distance <- units::set_units(22.56103, "m")
ratio <- desired_distance / st_length(path)
pt2 <- st_linesubstring(path, from = 0, to = ratio) %>% st_endpoint()

desired_distance <- units::set_units(44.38468, "m")
ratio <- desired_distance / st_length(path)
pt3 <- st_linesubstring(path, from = 0, to = ratio) %>% st_endpoint()

    (st_distance(pt1, pt2))
    Units: [m]
         [,1]
[1,] 22.56103
    (st_distance(pt1, pt3))
Units: [m]
         [,1]
[1,] 44.36801
```

I don't know why the accuracy of this method appears to scale with the distance but this error is acceptable for my task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to propose the following solution. As you can see, it has some
drawbacks, but I think it may fix your problem (depending on the required
spatial accuracy) First, load some packages

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(lwgeom)
#> Linking to liblwgeom 3.0.0beta1 r16016, GEOS 3.9.0, PROJ 7.2.1
```

Then, create the linestring object

```r
path <- st_as_sfc('LINESTRING(10 20, 11 21, 12 21, 13 22)', crs = 4326)
```

Calculate its length

```r
st_length(path)
#> 407726.3 [m]
```

If we want to estimate the point at distance 200000 [m] from the starting
point of the linestring, then we can use `st_linesubstring()`:

```r
desired_distance <- units::set_units(200000, "m")
ratio <- desired_distance / st_length(path)
(pt <- st_linesubstring(path, from = 0, to = ratio) %>% st_endpoint())
#> Warning in st_linesubstring.sfc(path, from = 0, to = ratio): st_linesubstring
#> does not follow a geodesic; you may want to use st_geod_segmentize first
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 11.46373 ymin: 21 xmax: 11.46373 ymax: 21
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> POINT (11.46373 21)
```

I’m not 100% sure about that warning message (and you may want to wait for other
answers or better explanations), but we can fix it by converting the input
object to a projected CRS. For example:

```r
path2 <- st_transform(path, 32632)
(pt2 <- st_linesubstring(path2, from = 0, to = ratio) %>% st_endpoint() %>% st_transform(4326))
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 11.46165 ymin: 21.00073 xmax: 11.46165 ymax: 21.00073
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> POINT (11.46165 21.00073)
```

The two points are not identical but quite close. They both lay around midway
in the linestring object.

```r
st_distance(pt, pt2)
#> Units: [m]
#>          [,1]
#> [1,] 230.2247
```

Plot

```r
par(mar = rep(0, 4))
plot(path, reset = FALSE)
plot(pt, add = TRUE, pch = 16, col = "darkgreen", cex = 3)
plot(pt2, add = TRUE, pch = 16, col = "darkred", cex = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. This works for my task. I've updated the example data with something more representative of my real data. When my CRS is set I get no error.

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks for sharing! as for the warning, it is perfectly normal (unfortunately) for spherical coordinates. Planar work just fine. There is interesting work going on with regards to the `s2` package that may eventually help, but it will take some time...