# find a list of coordinates x distance along linestring

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a road transect (linestring) and the distance (km) from start of the transect that each animal was sighted. To get the coordinate of the animals location along the transect, I have used code from this answer:
[Find coordinates x distance along linestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67987924/find-coordinates-x-distance-along-linestring)

However, I have 1,000s of locations to extract, can anyone help me to edit this code to allow me to pass a list of distances? I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)
path <- st_as_sfc('LINESTRING(10 20, 11 21, 12 21, 13 22)', crs = 4326)
st_length(path)
distances <- c(1,2,3)
desired_distance <- units::set_units(distances, "km")
ratio <- desired_distance / st_length(path)
pt <- st_linesubstring(path, from = 0, to = ratio) %>% st_endpoint()
st_coordinates(pt)
```

but it gives the error:

```
Error in CPL_linesubstring(x, from, to, tolerance) : 
  Expecting a single value: [extent=3].
```

And I'm not sure how to edit to accept a list of values

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I got around it with the following:

```
desired_distance = units::set_units(mydata$km, "km")
from = rep(0, each=length(desired_distance))
to = desired_distance / st_length(path)
results = vector("list", length(to))
for(i in seq_along(from)) { 
  results[[i]] = st_linesubstring(path, from[i], to[i]) %>% st_endpoint()  }
results = results %>% map_df(as_tibble) 
results = results %>% mutate(lon = unlist(map(results$geometry,1)),
         lat = unlist(map(results$geometry,2)))
```