# Extracting points on linestring based on distance from endpoint

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I have an sf linestring object in R with 22 features that represents a river. I also have a list of numbers that represent a fish's position, in miles from the downstream end of the river (0) over time. I have tried to use the methods outlined in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67987924/find-coordinates-x-distance-along-linestring) to solve this problem, but it returns the endpoints of all 22 features in the linestring object instead of 1 point that is the specified distance up the river. Below is the code I tried and the figure that results. Ignore the legend, that is a remnant of a previous figure.

```
desired_distance <- units::set_units(50000, "m")
ratio <- desired_distance / sum(st_length(EdNorthSF)) 
pt <- st_linesubstring(EdNorthSF, from = 0, to = ratio) %>% st_endpoint()
```

[image]

How can I modify this code so that I only get one point that the specified distance from the bottom of the river? Thanks so much in advance, and let me know if there's any additional info I can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Using {sf}, with `my_line` being you polyline, e.g.

```
## a horizontal line of length 10
my_line <- matrix(c(0, 10, 0, 0), , 2) |>
  st_linestring()
```

... you can `st_line_sample` at the relative line length(s) from 0 to 1. Say you want a point at distance 3.14 (map units) from start:

```
point_at_pi <- 
  my_line |>
  st_line_sample(sample = 3.14 / st_length(my_line))
```

```
my_line |> plot()
point_at_pi |> plot(col = 'red', add = TRUE)
```

[image: Point at 3.14 map units from line start]

Comment: That looks like it should work, but unfortunately it returns the error "st_line_sample for longitude/latitude not supported; use st_segmentize?" Is there a way to do the same thing using that function? Thank you for your previous reply, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Does `st_transform()`ing to an appropriate projection help (https://projectionwizard.org/ )? Latitude and longitude are in degrees (on an ellipsoid) and need to be projected before measuring distance. However, the most suitable projection varies with region and purpose, so this isn't done automatically.

Comment: Edit: the region of your example seems to be, at least partly, South Carolina, so EPSG 32133 might be a suitable projection code ( https://epsg.io/32133 ), and you could try `EdNorthSF |> st_transform(32133) |> st_line_sample(...) # etc.`