# Using R, how can I calculate distance along a LineString needed to get to a Point on the LineString?

Tags: r, geospatial

## Background

I have a set of station Points and a road LineString. I want to verify that the Points are located *along the road*. I'm not sure how that translates to GIS but my guess is:

1. **Proximity Check:**: The station should be close to its road.
2. **Boundary Check**: But it should not be near the endpoints of the road.

So in the picture below, only Station #3 is located along the road. Stations #1 and #4 fail the *Boundary Check* since they are near the road but near the endpoints. Station #2 has its nearest point in the middle road, but it's also too far away.

[Stations Nearby](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua88r.png)

**But ideally, I want a table like:**

| Station | Distance | % Along Road of Nearest Point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50m | 0 |
| 2 | 400m | 0.50 |
| 3 | 50m | 0.75 |
| 4 | 50m | 1 |

This way I can set different filters for *proximity* and *boundary* later on. I can try 50m within the middle 90%, 100m within the middle 80%, 1km within the middle 70%, and so forth.

## Problem

For the *proximity check*, I can use `st_distance(point, linestring)` to compute distance of a station Point to a road LineString.

And for the *boundary check*, I can find the nearest point with `near <- st_nearest_points(point, linestring)`. But then I don't know whether that point is 10% along the road, 50% along the road, or 99% of the road.

### A Not-So-Ideal Solution

The best solution I can come up with is limiting a LineString to its middle 80% with

```R
# create a bendy LineString
line <- st_linestring(
    matrix(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5), ncol = 2)
)

# Split line into 100 segments and take middle 80%
subset <- st_line_sample(line2, n = 100)
smaller_line <- st_linestring(st_coordinates(subset)[10:90,])

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = line) +
  geom_sf(data = subset) +
  geom_sf(data = smaller_line, color = "red") +
  theme_void()
```

[Middle 80% of a Road](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WHxC.png)

Then I can hardcode a proximity distance of say 100m and check if a station is 100m within the middle 80% of the road. But it doesn't get the table I ideally want.

### Different from an earlier question

I looked here already [Find coordinates x distance along linestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67987924/find-coordinates-x-distance-along-linestring). However, this is asking how to find a Point that's 500m along a Linestring. I'm trying to figure out how to find the distance (or % travelled) along a LineString to get to a Point.

In other words, it's asking `(LineString, distance) -> Point` while I'm asking `(LineString, Point) -> distance`